# Can i directly manipulate Internet Protocol to reinvent TCP?

Tags: tcp, ip

I'm not satisfied with some algorithms of TCP, and i know [it's not possible to implement TCP in UDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680592/can-tcp-be-implemented-via-udp). But i want to make a compatible layer with others server which relies on traditional TCP.

So i ask, can i manipulate IP directly on Linux or other *nix OS?

I know [udt](http://udt.sourceforge.net/) and other similar projects. I just need to keep the compatibility so that i don't need to do much works for so large amount of servers.

Comment: Exactly what part of TCP are you not satisfied with? There is nothing standing in your way to create a completely new network protocol on top of IP, but it sounds like a job not worth doing. Maybe rethinking your approach to networking is a better, and more worthwhile solution. No ones time is free, and making a new network protocol is a huge feat. That said, good luck too you if you are going to do it, but please consider other options as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remain compatible with other endpoints wich implement standard TCP then I assume you want to use the same protocol on the wire and make incremental improvements to it.

Your kernel's existing TCP implementation is in the kernel. If you want to improve it, I would say you had better make changes there rather than reinvent it. If you want to reinvent it and implement a whole TCP stack in userspace, then, sure, you can do it, but it's going to be A LOT OF WORK.